# How to move azure linked VSTS/DevOps to another account/azure subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to move an VSTS/DevOps instance from one azure environment to another. Is this possible and if it is how do I do this?

So for example Azure environment "A" owned by me has resource group "mydevops" with "devops" instance.
I want to move this to Azure environment "B" which is owned by a different person/account perhaps if needed including resource group.

Comment: You can take look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/change-azure-subscription?view=vsts).

Comment: Close, but can't move it to a subscription outside of my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need following permission to link and unlink Azure Subscription:

1. Project collection administrator or organization owner permissions
2. The owner or contributor role on your Azure subscription

So you need to have the owner or contributor role on both Azure A and Azure B to do this. Ohterwise, you need to add Azure B's owner to your Azure Devops account and give him PCA permission and ask him to link the subscription.